# sampling from confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, resampling

If we are provided a mean and (95%) confidence interval, is it possible to set up a system in which we draw random values that are outside the CIs 5% of the time?

My *intuition* is that if one can generate a distribution in which 68% of the random draws fall within a given interval, then it should also be possible to generate a distribution in which 95% of the draws fall within an interval.

Examples in R always helpful!

Comment: Are you provided with any form of sampling distribution?

Comment: @Alexis None. The confidence intervals were generated by bootstrap. However I have tried to keep it more general since I feel that by understanding this problem better, I will understand sampling in general much better.

Comment: Confidence interval talks about _mean_ response. Perhaps you would want prediction interval? The mean will stay the same, of course, but the confidence interval will be wider.

Comment: Err, you've already got a sampling distribution from the bootstrapping process. But there are arbitrary numbers of *other, different* distributions that have the same two moments that you've pulled out of it.

Comment: Another option is to sample from the confidence distribution, which is just the confidence associated with lower confidence bounds $(-\infty,x)$, its kind of like a frequentist posterior distribution.

Comment: I've assumed that all you have is the confidence interval obtained from the bootstrap, not the bootstrap distribution itself. If you do have the bootstrap outputs, then of course, there'd be no need to simulate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sampling from *any* distribution that has $\alpha_1$ of its probability below he lower limit of the CI and $0.05-\alpha_1$ of its probability above the upper limit of the CI (where $0\leq\alpha_1\leq 0.05$) should have the property you ask for.

So, you could choose a uniform distribution, or a normal distribution, or a t-distribution, or a Cauchy distribution - or almost anything else - as long as you chose the parameters so it had 2.5% of its probability below the lower limit and 2.5% of its probability above the upper limit. Sampling from that distribution will have 5% of its values outside the range.

e.g. Here's a 95% CI for the mean of a set of data: $(2893.238, 3061.930)$

So I could choose a uniform distribution, say.

If 90% of its probability is inside that range (of width 168.692), then the full range of the uniform is 168.692/0.9 = 187.436 wide. 2.5% of that is 4.686, so I need a uniform that runs from 2893.236-4.686 to 3061.930+4.686.

5% of the values from that uniform will lie outside the CI.

Comment: Thank you, somehow this just was not clicking for me.

Comment: The result of such simulation obviously depends quite a lot on your choice of distribution. I'd suggest a t-distribution would be a reasonable default choice. If it's unclear how to do that I could elaborate further.